# Chaves estrangeiras na modelagem do banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, relacionamento, chave-estrangeira

Uma chave primária pode ter duas chaves estrangeiras em tabelas diferentes? Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chave primária da tabela Lucros pode ser chave estrangeira/externa de outras tabelas, neste caso tens:

Faturamento

```
 PK->codFaturamento
 FK->codLucro
```

Lucros

```
PK->codLucro
```

Despesas

```
PK->codDespesa

FK->codLucro
```

Nestes casos, um relacionamento de 1:N

Comment: Então esta correto ?

Comment: Sim está correcto!